# Unable to set activedefrag yes in Redis server

Tags: redis, ubuntu-22.04

I have a Redis cluster that is constantly at a memory fragmentation ratio of about 2.

I was trying to enable `activedefrag` by running `CONFIG SET activedefrag yes` in `redis-cli`, but I received the error message:

> (error) ERR Invalid argument 'yes' for CONFIG SET 'activedefrag' - Active defragmentation cannot be enabled: it requires a Redis server compiled with a modified Jemalloc like the one shipped by default with the Redis source distribution

The redis-server package shipped with Ubuntu 22.04 is 6.0 and the version string looks like it was compiled with jemalloc.

```
# redis-server --version
Redis server v=6.0.16 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.2.1 bits=64 build=a3fdef44459b3ad6
```

ldd confirms that it is linked to libjemalloc.

```
# ldd `which redis-server`
        ...
        libjemalloc.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.2 (0x00007f0428b26000)
```

When setting the option in the config file redis-server fails to start with a similar error message.

Is there any option I am missing or do I need to compile Redis myself to be able to use defragmentation? I could not find any [configuration option](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/redis/redis/6.0/redis.conf) to "enable" jemalloc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started a docker container with the official `redis:6.0` image and here the setting works, and the version string looks basically identical.

```
root@42613c835e31:/data# redis-server --version
Redis server v=6.0.19 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.1.0 bits=64 build=3aa1eb72f68fbe5e
root@42613c835e31:/data# redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> CONFIG SET activedefrag yes
OK
```

But `ldd` shows that it is NOT linked to a jemalloc library:

```
root@42613c835e31:/data# ldd `which redis-server`
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe4a9a2000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f5b6aa41000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5b6aa3b000)
        libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f5b6a9a8000)
        libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f5b6a6b3000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5b6a691000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5b6a4bd000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5b6afa2000)
```

It looks like the Ubuntu package is NOT compiled with the needed *modified* jemalloc library, but uses the Ubuntu default instead.

So the only options I currently see are:

- use the Docker Redis container image
- compile Redis yourself
- **use the [Redis APT repository](https://redis.io/docs/getting-started/installation/install-redis-on-linux/)**

The package from the Redis repo is compiled with the modified jemalloc, the activedefrag config works with it. This seems to be the most promising option, as updates will be handled automatically with regular system updates. I'll try to switch from the Ubuntu package to it next.